# Create iframe in the middle of the page

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, alignment

Long story short. I need to create an iframe with javascript and align it in the center of the page.

I found this nice piece of code:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
var html = '<body>Foo</body>';
iframe.src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(html);
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
console.log('iframe.contentWindow =', iframe.contentWindow);
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix the alignment to be centered? The reason for choosing an iframe to begin with is because I want the frame to be independent of the current page's CSS styles.

/Patrik

Comment: `iframe{width: 50%; left: 25%; height: 50vh; top: 25vh; position:fixed;z-index:9999; box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vw rgba(0,0,0,0.75);}`

Comment: That did not work out so well. :)

http://jsfiddle.net/9k9Pe/1115/

Comment: using the correct syntax does ;) http://jsfiddle.net/9k9Pe/1116/

Comment: You sir, are a genius! Make it an answer so I can award you with the points? :)

Comment: i'm sure it's already been answered, just glad to help. don't forget the height.

Comment: Cheers man! Much obliged!

Answer (score 1):

1- Get browser window size

2- Get iframe width and height

3- Substract number 2 from number 1

4- Divide rounding the resultby 2

And that way you'll have the x and y coordinates for your iframe to locate it in the center of the browser window.

Comment: and what if the browser resizes or scrolls?

Comment: The function should be applied to both events: load and resize :)

Comment: The scrolling could be tackle with css position: fixed, but I don't know if it's a requirement to keep the iframe always visible.

Comment: I'm with you when it comes to finding out the coordinates (and that's helpful), but I have still not found a way of moving it around except for margin.

Margin-right/left/top does not seem to work and marginwidth/height did not do it for me either according to http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

It'd be nice if the iframe moves when resizing but it's not necessary at the moment. :)

Comment: if you want to use margin (ex: :1px auto;), make sure the container and iframe are display:block;